# When querying using OPENJSON, will the result set mimic the order of the JSON array or will the order be random?

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json

Let's say I have this JSON array:

```
[{
    "Field": "1"
}, {
    "Field": "2"
}, {
    "Field": "3"
}]
```

And I use that in an `OpenJSON` query in SQL Server.

Will the query result set be always the same order as the array:

```
Field
1
2
3
```

Or will it be random just like any normal Select query without an order by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of JSON array and `OPENJSON()` call with default schema, based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value), the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and the `key` column holds the index of the element in the specified array. If you want to get an ordered set, you should use a statement like the following:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{ "Field": "1" }, { "Field": "2" }, { "Field": "3" }]'

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])

-- or

SELECT c.Field
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value]) WITH (Field int '$.Field') c
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key])
```

Comment: What are the chances that the result set from the OPENJSON() query with no order by clause result in an order that is not following the key or the order of the array?

Comment: If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` then the order of the rows is completely arbitrary. It'll be in what ever order SQL Server processes the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answers